# I want to display a column of Excel in the form of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have one column in my excel file, i have to convert all the rows of the  column into a dictionary format.my file like this with 802 rows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJnNB.png)

and my expected output:

```
ldict = {
"item1": set(["5"]),
"item2": set(["2"]),
"item3": set(["0"]),
"item4": set(["1"]),
"item5": set(["6"]),
"item6": set(["6"]),
"item7": set(["1"]),
```

}
please help me.

Comment: try this... [{'item{}'.format(i),data[0][i]} for i in range(len(data))]

Comment: Have you made any effort whatsoever to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package (if you don't have it already), and then do:

```
import openpyxl

# Access active worksheet of excel file
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('workbook.xlsx')
sheet = book.active

# Access first column
column = sheet['A']

# Use dictionary comprehension on the cells in the column
d = {
    'item{}'.format(num): cell.value
    for (num, cell) in enumerate(column, 1)
}
```